# Chrome Extension: onCompleted event doesn't fire for frameId == 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that would augment behavior in LinkedIn. I set a `webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener`. I only want to run my code after the page is "completely" resolved. I plan do to this by leveraging the following:

> A note about frame IDs
>
> Frames within a tab can be identified by a frame ID. The frame ID of
>   the main frame is always 0, the ID of child frames is a positive
>   number. Once a document is constructed in a frame, its frame ID
>   remains constant during the lifetime of the document. As of Chrome 49,
>   this ID is also constant for the lifetime of the frame (across
>   multiple navigations).

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated

The code, built on this model is this.

```
  if (details.frameId == 0){
    console.log("%c Saw frameId 0", 'color: green');
  } else {
    console.log("%c Saw frameId != 0; guarding", 'color: tomato');
    return;
  }
```

When refreshing the page, I see `frameId` 0 (yes!). But when I visit other parts of the site and navigate back to the same location, I *don't* see frameId0. The screenshot shows a "hard refresh" experience and (after the mark) a navigate-to experience.

So my question is this: how can I reliably know when the *accursed* page is truly loaded. I thought the `frameId == 0` would be the magic bullet, but it continues to stymie.

My *hypothesis* is that turbolinks or Ember is somehow inhibiting that signal, but am investigating further. Is there a better event to track?

Thanks!

Comment: Modern SPA sites don't [re]load the page on navigation so onCompleted fires just on the first load. For intra navigation you can use onHistoryStateUpdated and onReferenceFragmentUpdated.

Comment: I figured it had to be that. I was just not too much a fan of having to DRY out the code between the two events. But....HOKAY. :)